# Sort List Ascending and write to ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to ask how to sort list by date time. I have class task

```
 public class tasks
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Datum narození
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime expires { get; set; }
.
.
.
}
```

class data

```
 public class data
{
   public List<tasks> tsk = new List<tasks>();

public data()
    {
    }


 public void AddTask(string name, DateTime expires)
    {          
        tasks ts = new tasks(name, expires.Date);
        tsk.Add(ts);
    }
```

In Main program, I stores data in a List.

```
private data dt = new data();


dt.AddTask(textBox1.Text, dateTimePicker1.Value);
```

I would like to write data to the listbox sortAscending.

Comment: please post list definition

Comment: Did you already stumbled across SortedList http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx

Comment: You manage to have two typos in 4 lines of code.  `MyLIst` should have lower case `i`.  `Add()` needs a capital `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort using LINQ and then place it into the list box using AddRange:

```
MyList m = new MyList();

m.Add("n1", DateTime.Now);
m.Add("n2", DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
m.Add("n3", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));

var sortedList = from i in m
    orderby i.expires
    select i;
listBox1.Items.AddRange(sortedList.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell how MyLIst is defined, but if it is one of the standard collections this should work.

```
var result = MyList.OrderBy(x => x.expires).Select(x => x);
```

Comment: Select(x => x) is redundant

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - It is a style thing -- I expect there will need to be a type change to make it easy to add to the select list.

Comment: If the type you're iterating over is a IEnumerable, that Select(x => x) will result in a redundant O(n) operation.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - ummm. No.  I looked at the IL of both of them and the difference is a function call not a loop.  O(1)

Comment: Really? My bad then. i was certain it was projecting the whole list and iterating over it.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - There is one iteration over the whole list for the OrderBy, but Select and other Linq calls don't need to.  In fact, by itself Select is Lazy -- it is only invoked when needed.  (This can be  a source of bugs)